# Seeing difference between mercurial clones

Tags: mercurial

I am using mercurial (hg) and have several repositories that are similar to each other (clones). I could like to diff the repositories, just looking at nodes, parents, children, hashes.

Is there a tool that will allow me to do a diff of the repositories? For a graphical tool it would show the combined dag, with each sub-dag in a different colour. A command line way of doing this would also be of value, though I suspect a visual tool to be better.

I am not asking how to view differences between a file/directory in different repositorys.

I am using Gnu/Linux and Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg incoming` in CLI or corresponding button in TortoiseHG

It will not show DAG of missed changeset on top of existing repo-DAG, but separate DAG of incoming (explorable) changesets in TortoiseHG or list of changesets in case of CLI usage

Comment: This works, though in tortoise-hg I feel nervous clicking the check incoming button, it is next to the pull button and looks similar (same for outgoing/push).

Comment: Well, an accidental pull can always be reverted with hg rollback.

Comment: The push function has a confirmation box on it so that shouldn't scare you either.